# Detect if an activity restarted because of an orientation change

Tags: android

How can I detect if the user changed the device orientation so I don't run the same initialization code every time the activity is recreated? Or how can I restore my activity state (including variables values)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way is to use [onSavedInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). This will save the state of your `Activity` and variables.

The way I typically do it, and is said to be a last resort in the docs, is to handle the configuration change yourself. In the `manifest` you can declare

```
<activity
    ...
     android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

then in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // add logic here if you need
}
```