# What happens to a static textview during onCreate()

Tags: java, android

I have a static textview that has a certain default value set in the XML. Later, I set that variable to something else, but whenever the orientation changes, the value of the static variable returns to the default, even though I'm not reinitializing it. Why might this be? Shouldn't the value persist even after onCreate() is called?

Comment: When orientation changes the activity is destroyed and recreated. So when the activity is destroyed and recreated the values of variables are set to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onCreate()` gets called I'm guessing you also call `setContentView()` as normal. This redraws all of the `Views` with the default values. You need to handle the configuration changes

[See this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753504/detect-if-an-activity-restarted-because-of-an-orientation-change/15753620#15753620) on how to handle it. The recommended way is to use `onSavedInstanceState` but I normally handle it myself and haven't had any problems...yet

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the [lifecycle of an Android app.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) Whenever you rotate, your application goes through all the lifecycle method calls. You need to store the current state within a Bundle and restore that data in your `onCreate` after the rotation has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

During orientation change Android re-creates all layouts. To save the state of the widget you can simply assign an `id` to the TextView element:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_caption"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP is doing this but this in no way saves the state by simply assigning an id to it

Comment: Ah, sorry. BTW Android saves the state of some widgets with specified id. But not all views with an ID save their state. Android widgets, with an ID, whose state can be changed by the user, appear to save their state on a soft kill. So EditText saves its state, but TextView does not save its state. I've forgot it.